# Lie algebras with unique invariant scalar product

Tags: lie-algebras

Every 1-dimensional or simple complex Lie algebra admits an invariant, symmetric and non-degenerate bilinear form. This form is unique up to multiplication by a nonzero constant (which in Yang-Mills theories plays the role of the coupling constant).

Are there other Lie algebras with such a unique scalar product?

Comment: A reductive Lie algebra splits as the (commuting) direct sum of a commutative Lie algebra and many simple Lie algebras, so it supports a unique such form if and only if it is 1-dimensional commutative, or is actually simple.  A general Lie algebra splits as the direct sum of its radical and a reductive Lie algebra.  Obviously the reductive part must be as above.  I'm not sure about the rest.

Comment: It does not split as a Lie algebra. In general you found yourself with a semi direct product.

Comment: If you have an invariant, symmetric and non-degenerate bilinear form as stated, and, if $\mathfrak i$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak g$. Then, the orthogonal $\mathfrak i ^{\perp}$ of $\mathfrak i$ is also an ideal and your algebra $\mathfrak g$ splits as $\mathfrak i + \mathfrak i ^\perp$. So, for a non reductive algebra, you don't even have one such a bilinear form.

Comment: @InfiniteLooper, yes, sorry, I am in the bad habit of writing "commuting direct sum" and "direct sum" in place of "direct sum" and "semi-direct product" for Lie algebras.  Why couldn't we have an isotropic ideal ($\mathfrak i = \mathfrak i^\perp$)?

Comment: Yes you are right, It works for semi simple algebras because the non degenerate Killing form induces on an ideal, the Killing form of the ideal.

Comment: I wanted to show that having such a bilnear form is the same as being reductive but this tends to be false.

Comment: @InfiniteLooper It's indeed far from true: for instance for every Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, the semidirect product $\mathfrak{g}\ltimes\mathfrak{g}^*$ has such a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form (easy to figure out). Here where $\mathfrak{g}^*$ is viewed as abelian ideal and endowed with the coadjoint representation of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra with  an invariant, symmetric and non-degenerate bilinear form $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle $.

**Claim : $\mathfrak g$ admits only one such a bilinear form if and only if $\mathfrak g $ is either simple or abelian and one dimensional.**

*Proof* : Denote the Levi decomposition of $\mathfrak g$ by $\mathfrak r + \mathfrak s$, then for any $\lambda \in \mathbb R $ the form defined by
$$\langle r_1 + s_1 , r_2 + s_2 \rangle_\lambda = \langle r_1 , r_2 \rangle + \langle s_1 , r_2 \rangle + \langle r_1 , s_2 \rangle  +\lambda \langle s_1 , s_2 \rangle $$
Is invariant.
For some $\lambda$ around 1, the form is also definite because it is an open property.

Having only one such form implies that $\mathfrak g$ is either solvable and equal to $\mathfrak r$ or semi-simple and equal to $\mathfrak s$.
We know that in the semi-simple case, only simple ones have only one such form.
Assume from now on, that $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak r$ is solvable.
We write $\mathfrak g = [\mathfrak g , \mathfrak g] + A$ as a direct sum of vector spaces and as before for some $\lambda$ the bilinear form defined by
$$\langle g_1 + a_1 , g_2 + a_2 \rangle_\lambda = \langle g_1 , g_2 \rangle + \langle g_1 , a_2 \rangle + \langle a_1 , g_2 \rangle  +\lambda \langle a_1 , a_2 \rangle $$
is symmetric and definite.

Comment: Here's a slight variant of the proof, not using Levi. If $\mathfrak{g}$ is not simple or $\le 1$-dimensional, then it has a quotient that is simple or $\le 1$-dimensional. Since $\mathfrak{g}$ has a non-degenerate invariant bilinear form $b_0$ and this quotient too, it also admits a degenerate non-zero invariant bilinear form $b_1$. Hence the space of invariant bilinear forms on $\mathfrak{g}$ has dimension $\ge 2$. So it contains 2 non-proportional non-degenerate elements (say $b_0+tb_1$ for all but finitely many scalars $t$).

Comment: Also the result (and proof) works over an arbitrary field of characteristic zero, when in the statement "simple" is replaced with "absolutely simple". (For a simple, non-absolutely-simple Lie algebra, the dimension of the space of invariant symmetric bilinear forms is $\ge 2$.)

Comment: Using this approach you show that the dimension of such bilinear form is greater than the length of maximal chains of composition in the Lie algebra. Can you show the equality ?

Comment: If the abelianization has dimension $n$ this dimension is $\ge n^2$ ($\ge n(n+1)/2$ for the symmetric part).

Comment: By the way, no, I don't prove the inequality you claim. Indeed first it would require a *normal* composition series (not only subnormal). Second would it require all the quotients to admit a non-degenerate invariant form, which is usually not the case.

Comment: Actually I can think of an $n$-dimensional nilpotent Lie algebra (for all odd $n\ge 5$) for which this dimension is $5$ ($4$ for symmetric ones), while chains have length $n$.

Comment: Thanks you InfiniteLooper and YCor.

Comment: Now I would like to drop the condition of non-degeneracy:  Can you characterize all complex Lie algebras admitting a (up to multiplication) unique invariant, symmetric bilinear form?  One easy example is the 2-dimensional Lie algebra [x,y]=y.

Comment: In general, for given $\mathfrak{g}$ let $K$ be the intersection of all kernels of all [symmetric] invariant bilinear forms. Then these are those for which $\mathfrak{g}/K$ is simple or 1-dimensional. Remains to understand $K$, and this goes along with understanding Lie algebras admitting a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form.

Answer (score 3):

I. Bajo and S. Benayadi already gave a complete answer for your question in their paper entitled "[Lie algebras admitting a unique quadratic structure](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927879708826023)" in 1997, there you can find much more detail.

Comment: Actually all details were given in the proofs above, e.g. in my 5-line comment. Anyway it's useful to have a published reference.