# Lie algebras with unique invariant bilinear symmetric form

Tags: lie-algebras

A complex, finite dimensional Lie algebra admitting a (up to multiplication by a non-zero scalar) unique, invariant, symmetric, non-degenerate bilinear form is 1-dimensional or simple. Cf ['Lie algebras with unique invariant scalar product' June 20 2019](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334437/lie-algebras-with-unique-invariant-scalar-product).

I would like to drop the non-degeneracy:

> Can you characterize all complex Lie algebras admitting a (up to multiplication) unique, invariant, symmetric bilinear form?

One easy example is the 2-dimensional Lie algebra [x,y]=y.

Comment: Well, it characterizes the Lie algebra $\{0\}$ (assuming you mean "unique up to nonzero scalar multiplication", and also if you mean unique at all).

Comment: Maybe you mean to replace "non-degenerate" with "non-zero" (and keep "up to nonzero scalar multiplication"), in which case the question will be less trivial, but the answer will be a bit disappointing. First, say "so-simple" to mean simple or 1-dimensional abelian. Then you get the Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ with a single so-simple quotient $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{n}$ (and hence $\mathfrak{g}$ either perfect  [solvable-by-simple] or solvable with 1-dim abelianization), with no other quotient having a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form. This is a huge class.

Comment: So well, among those Lie algebras with a single so-simple quotient, I'd say that "generically" all Lie algebras satisfy your property. For instance, all solvable 3-dimensional with 1-dim abelianization do, and all 4-dim do, with the exception of the oscillator algebra. For $\mathfrak{s}$ simple and $V$ irreducible $\mathfrak{s}$-module, the semidirect product $\mathfrak{s}\ltimes V$ satisfies your property iff $V$ is not the adjoint representation.

Comment: Small modifications to a question with an unsatisfactory answer sometimes indicate that there is an unspecified bigger question lurking behind the scenes.  Is that true?  If so, what is it?